# AWS Lambda to copy last modified object from S3 to another S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to create an AWS Lambda function using Python that identifies the last modified object in an S3 bucket and then copies them off to another S3 object. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Why not just use the built-in AWS S3 replication feature?

Comment: What you're saying is possible, but S3 is really not built to allow you to query/sort easily for objects by modification date/creation date. Could you share a little bit more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen I am generating multiple files in a s3 bucket, one at a time and once the last file is generated then they need to be copied off of to another s3 bucket, in the reverse order of their creation time. Hence, the file that was created last should be the first one to be copied to the other s3 bucket and the 1st file created should be the last one to be copied and so on.